# swf file caching issue when passing parameters in url in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am loading one swf file inside a main swf by using swfloader. and i am passing parameters to the loading swf file by appending to the url.

My issue is this loading swf is not caching because each time that passing parameters are changing. my sample code is as follows

```
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain; 
context.applicationDomain = new ApplicationDomain(); 
patViewId.loaderContext = context;
patViewId.source = "/Sample/view/flex/file21.swf?patientCode="+patCode;
```

is there any solution to achieve caching for this swf file.. can somebody help me on this..?

Comment: Browser caches resources by their full URLs which include parameters. To keep URL the same, you need to pass these parameters some other way around, LocalConnection, maybe?

Comment: Thanks for your help... can you please provide me some working example or link for data passing to swf using LocalConnection.

Comment: I don't have one at hand, but there are plenty out there. Google > **as3 localconnection example**

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any variables straight to the loadercontext:

```
context.parameters = {'patientCode': patCode};
```

In your loaded swf (file21.swf) you should be able to access the parameters like this:

```
loaderInfo.parameters.patientCode
```

Comment: But we are using flex sdk 3.2.0. In this version parameters property is not available for loadercontext. can you please suggest any other way.

Comment: This is solved my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354825/pass-data-to-child-swf-after-swf-loading-completed/48357825#48357825