# pass data to child swf after swf loading completed

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I am loading one swf file inside a main swf by using swfloader and i want to pass the parameters to the loaded swf. How can i get the loaded child reference to pass data.
My sample code is as follows

TestFile1.mxml

```
public var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, myFun);
loader.load(new URLRequest("/view/flex/TestFile2.swf"), new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain));
viewId.addChild(loader);        

public function myFun(event:Event):void{
    Alert.show("loader.content-"+loader.content); // here alert coming like this [object_TestFile2_mx_managers_SystemManager]
    var testfile2:TestFile2 = loader.content as TestFile2; // here testfile2 is null
    testfile2.param1 = "val1";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options.

1. If you just need simple startup values, you can pass arguments in the loader string and have TestFile2 grab them on start.

   new URLRequest("/view/flex/TestFile2.swf?param1=val1")
2. If you need to interact with the child, you need to grab a reference to it after the application complete event. `Event.COMPLETE` only fires when the loader is loaded. In the `Event.COMPLETE` event, add an event to fire when the content is ready.

   ```
   public function myFun(event:Event):void{
       Alert.show("loader.content-"+loader.content); // here alert coming like this [object_TestFile2_mx_managers_SystemManager]
       loader.content.addEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, appCreationComplete);
   }
   private function appCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
   {
       var testfile2:TestFile2 = loader.content["application"] as  TestFile2; // here testfile2 is not null
       testfile2.param1 = "val1";
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much. we need the second one & it is working for me.